# Objective-C reading file content returns incorrect encoded text with NSUTF8StringEncoding

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, encoding, utf-8

I have an app that has a script which reads file for json content. Script is:

```
    NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", jsonString);
    //filepath debug log: /var/mobile/Applications/1394B0D1-5B12-445D-BDFA-7B1E2661B685/Documents/json_branch_1_ru
```

In iPhone Simulator everything works perfect, returning text is correct:

> {"id":1,"add":"Казахстан, Алматы, улица Толе би,
>   73а","lon":"43.254677","lat":"76.934434","bnkid":42,"al":"","rat":10,"prod":"","valid":1,"wrktime":"с физ. лицами: понедельник-пятница: 09:00-18:00 с юр. лицами: Нет
>   данных"}

When I test app on my **device**, returning text encoding is incorrect:

> {"id":1,"add":"–ö–∞–∑–∞—Ö—Å—Ç–∞–Ω, –ê–ª–º–∞—Ç—ã, —É–ª–∏—Ü–∞ –¢–æ–ª–µ
>   –±–∏,
>   73–∞","lon":"43.254677","lat":"76.934434","bnkid":42,"al":"","rat":10,"prod":"","valid":1,"wrktime":"—Å
>   —Ñ–∏–∑. –ª–∏—Ü–∞–º–∏: –ø–æ–Ω–µ–¥–µ–ª—å–Ω–∏–∫-–ø—è—Ç–Ω–∏—Ü–∞:
>   09:00-18:00 —Å —é—Ä. –ª–∏—Ü–∞–º–∏: –ù–µ—Ç
>   –¥–∞–Ω–Ω—ã—Ö"},{"id":2,"add":"–ö–∞–∑–∞—Ö—Å—Ç–∞–Ω, –ê–ª–º–∞—Ç—ã,
>   –º–∫—Ä. 5,
>   30","lon":"43.231442","lat":"76.867923","bnkid":42,"al":"","rat":10,"prod":"","valid":1,"wrktime":"09:00
>   - 18:00"}

What is the problem?
**Note:**
1. My file doesn't have extension
2. File saved with utf-8 encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem.
The problem was **Line Breaks or tabs** in json text. Somehow it damaged text encoding.